# Scheduler for Informatica BDM in AWS environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, informatica

We have a requirement of loading Amazon S3 bucket by pulling data from external RDBMS database using sqoop jobs. I have created a shell script which has sqoop jobs to perform the task, I mentioned. After creating an object in Amazon S3 bucket, I would like to trigger the Informatica Developer workflows which will perform the task of loading data from one bucket to another bucket after performing business logic.

I know, we can call the Informatica workflows through shell script or through Informatica's own scheduler itself. I have used Autosys earlier where we configure shell script as job and trigger the Informatica workflow after completion of the of this shell script keeping dependencies.

My question is, Do we have any open source scheduler available to configure Informatica BDM jobs in AWS?

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for apache airflow . You can use the following link to understand the integration. This uses informatica's capability plus apache airflow scheduling

https://network.informatica.com/community/informatica-network/products/big-data/big-data-management/blog/2018/05/30/integrating-bdm-with-apache-airflow

Comment: Thanks V.Sha, I will try this scheduling tool.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Airflow make a lot sense incase of INFA BDM as INDA BDM jobs can be triggered using shell commands which can be easily triggered using Airflow bash operator as mention below:

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='INFA_TASK',
    bash_command='./sh infacmd.sh wfs startWorkflow -dn MyDomain -sn MyDataIntSvs -un MyUser -pd MyPassword -a MyApplication -wf MyWorkflow',
    dag=dag)